# Define new Python timezone

Tags: python, timezone

I'm trying to define a timezone that is a constant -8 hour offset from UTC.  Not US/Pacific, which changes throughout the year, not Pitcairn, which is not where my data is (so is semantically misleading), but something that makes contextual sense and can be used with standard Python datetime functions.

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects?

Comment: Ah yes, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am very curious.  Why do you want to do this?  IMHO, there are very few scenarios where custom time zones are practical. If you have a real-world use case, I'm dying to hear about it.

Comment: Good question!  I maintain a set of tools for managing air quality data emitted by the Oregon Department of Envrionmental Quality.  As you can see on their website (https://oraqi.deq.state.or.us/home/map), the data carries the notice "Data on this site is presented in Standard Time at the time the measurement ended. There is no adjustment for Daylight Saving Time during its use from March to November.", hence the need for a customized timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty simple:

```
from datetime import timezone

my_tz = timezone(timedelta(hours=-8), name="OrDeq")
```